# How to get SVN to ignore Mac "._" files?

Tags: svn

My development server is accessed by several OSX users, and their OS tends to leave lots of unnecessary files around the place, all starting with dot underscore ("`._`"). I know OSX can be told not to create these on network drives, but they still sneak in. I'd like SVN to ignore anything starting with "`._`", but I can't seem to get it to work, even though it looks like it should be simple. I've added "`._*`" to the SVN global ignore pattern, but SVN is still trying to add and commit these files. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? My full SVN ignore pattern is:

```
global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store Thumbs.db ._* *.bak *.tmp nbproject
```

I don't know if it makes any difference, but I'm trying to set this on both Ubuntu and Ubuntu server by editing the /etc/subversion/config file.

Comment: How do they access to the server? Did you set the ignore pattern on OSX clients?

Comment: They access the server over samba, and commit from the server. I can set the ignore on their machines, but I'll still have the same problem where I'm committing a folder they've worked on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have a [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that might fit the bill. This hook allows you to completely ban the use of certain file names based upon a regular expression. You can ban any file that starts with "._" and if someone tries to add one, they won't be able to commit it.

After a few rejected commits due to having "._" files, developers will update their `global-ignores` to include those files.

You can't set `global-ignores` for all of your users, but this pre-commit hook will encourage your users to set it on their own.

It works on the same principle of how electric sockets discourage users from sticking a fork into them. After the third or fourth time, even the most stubborn developers learn that it's not a good idea.

Comment: That looks brilliant, thankyou. Solves the problem without relying on the other SVN users to do anything. Spot on.

Comment: @JonMitten The new link is https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook. This puts everything in a more public place.

Comment: What happens if you put a fork into electric sockets?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use set the svn:ignore property and add "._*" and other desired values to it. Then the ignore values are in the repository and each working copy, rather than machine-specific configuration. However, both svn:ignore and the global ignore list can be circumvented.

#### Make sure the form of "svn add" you are using respects svn:ignore and the global ignore list.

Here is an excerpt from the [svn docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) (added emphasis):

> **Even if svn:ignore is set, you may run
>   into problems if you use shell
>   wildcards in a command**. Shell
>   wildcards are expanded into an
>   explicit list of targets before
>   Subversion operates on them, so
>   running svn SUBCOMMAND * is just like
>   running svn SUBCOMMAND file1 file2
>   file3 …. In the case of the svn add
>   command, this has an effect similar to
>   passing the --no-ignore option. So
>   instead of using a wildcard, use svn
>   add --force . to do a bulk scheduling
>   of unversioned things for addition.
>   The explicit target will ensure that
>   the current directory isn't overlooked
>   because of being already under version
>   control, and the --force option will
>   cause Subversion to crawl through that
>   directory, adding unversioned files
>   while still honoring the svn:ignore
>   property and global-ignores runtime
>   configuration variable. Be sure to
>   also provide the --depth files option
>   to the svn add command if you don't
>   want a fully recursive crawl for
>   things to add.

#### How to test if your ignore list is working

```
svn status
```

If it doesn't show up, and it's not versioned, then it is being properly ignored.

Barring proper ignores AND always using add appropriately, a pre commit hook like @David W. mentioned may be the last/only total defense...

Comment: That's great information, thanks. I had no idea that the svn add would have issues with shell wildcards etc, so that will be really handy. I think the pre-commit hook is going to be the most reliable, given that people are using different machines and clients, etc, but wanted to say thanks for your answer as well because it is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion uses the fnmatch() function for the ignores. So you have to use the [pattern matching notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13) of that function.

The ignore section you posted should work. Are you sure you are setting it in the correct config file? There are [multiple locations](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1) where svn reads those from.

> On Unix-like systems, this area appears as a directory named .subversion in the user's home directory.
>   In addition to the per-user configuration area, Subversion also recognizes the existence of a system-wide configuration area. [..] On Unix-like platforms, the system-wide configuration area is expected to be the /etc/subversion directory;

Comment: I believe I'm setting it in the right place, because the other items I've been adding to the ignore are being correctly ignored. I will check, though. Thanks for the pattern matching link - interesting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't adding files to SVN a local operation? In this case, the user-specific settings should ignore the files.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to get ._* files since the devs work directly on the server, so ._ files are directly generated when they edit files.

They should instead grab a working copy on their local machine (see Subversion docs for how to do it from a samba server), then the ignore pattern (set on each machine) will prevent them to add ._* files when they commit. In other words these files will "stay on their machine".

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a client-side hook to recursively delete the ._* files?

I have an alias in my bash shell to remove all .DS_Store folders, wiring up that to Subversion is something I should look into …